# pg_restore "CREATE CAST" not executed if using public or pg_catalog schemas

Tags: postgresql, migration, postgresql-9.6, pg-dump, pg-restore

While moving database to another instance I'm using `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` with intermediate file.

Dump file was created like this:

```
pg_dump --host $SRC_DB_HOST --port 5432 "dbname=$SRC_DB user=$SRC_DB_USER sslrootcert=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem sslmode=verify-full" --no-owner --verbose -Fc --file db.bak
```

I definitely see that there are casts in the dump

```
$strings db.bak | grep "CREATE \(TYPE\|CAST\)"
CREATE TYPE public.score_group_name AS ENUM (
CREATE TYPE public.score_group_type AS ENUM (
CREATE CAST (character varying AS public.score_group_name) WITH INOUT AS IMPLICIT;
CREATE CAST (character varying AS public.score_group_type) WITH INOUT AS IMPLICIT;
```

But when I restore database running `pg_restore` with params:

```
pg_restore --verbose -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -n public --single-transaction db.bak > migration.log
```

there are no queries produced for creating it:

```
$ grep -e "\(CREATE\|DROP\) \(TYPE\|CAST\)" migration.log
CREATE TYPE public.score_group_name AS ENUM (
CREATE TYPE public.score_group_type AS ENUM (
```

Source PostgreSQL version:

```
PostgreSQL 9.6.11 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9), 64-bit
```

Target PostgreSQL version:

```
PostgreSQL 9.6.10 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4, 64-bit
```

PostgreSQL Utils versions:

```
$ pg_dump --version
pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 9.6.14
$ pg_restore --version
pg_restore (PostgreSQL) 9.6.14
```

**UPDATE**
It seems that the root of the problem is `-n public` parameter, without schema filtering -- `CREATE CAST` statement is produced, but which schema should I add to the restore? Because `-n public` and `-n pg_catalog` filter out such statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that type casts do not live in a schema.

If you specify `-n public`, you will only get objects from that schema, and that does not include the type cast.